# How to retrieve the Json response having attachment

Tags: json, rest-assured

There is a GET API REST call request, on executed gives a zip file and here are the headers for the response

```
content-disposition →attachment;filename="results.zip"  
content-type →text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

On Postman, we can do `Send and Download` and can save the resultant zip file

I use `RestAssured` to test the REST API calls.

Can somebody help me how to retrieve the resultant zip file from the API call?

Answer (score 1):

Update:
I found a solution from Rest Assured, where we can get the Response as either InputStream or Byte Array and further write to a ZipFile.

As InputStream:-

```
    // Get the response as Input Stream
    InputStream is = result.getBody().asInputStream();
    OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Test.zip");
    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        stream.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
    System.out.println("Zip file captured successfully");
```

As ByteArray:-

// Get the response as ByteArray

```
byte[] arraybyteResponse = result.getBody().asByteArray();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(arraybyteResponse);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Test.zip");
    WritableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(os);
    channel.write(buffer);
    System.out.println("Zip file captured successfully");
```